# Communicate between app and browser

Tags: swift, macos, url-scheme

I have a scenario in which I want my MacOS app and the browser to communicate:

When the user presses a button, it's opening the browser

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "myServerUrl")!)
```

The browser does something and then it should return the result to my app.

I thought about 2 ways to do it:

1. Find (somehow) an open port, open the browser with something like
   that `NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string:"myServerUrl/?port=8090")!)`

   And then when the browser would have the result, it will access my
   app via the agreed port with something like

   ```
   http://localhost:8090/?res=3434343
   ```
2. Just use URL-scheme:

   `NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "myServerUrl/?openapp=myapp")!)`

   and then the browser would use this to send the data to my app.

So my question is, which way is "better"?
Are both ways valid?

And I'll probably need this feature for iOS soon, so I'll prefer something that works on both platforms.

Comment: How sensitive is the data that's being worked with? Is it really bad if someone fabricates the app's message or the server response ?

Comment: not sensitive at all

Comment: I would do the second option simply because it’s very simple. It very easy to open a URL, and pretty easy to open an app from a URL with a parameter.

Comment: Great, thanks! But just to know better..what if the data was sensitive?

Comment: It would of course need to be over https, and I would have used some form of expiring secret so that the server can verify the request is authentic.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!